# How to get a value from ASPxDataEdit and ASPxComboBox

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

How do I get a selected date from `ASPxDateEdit` and `ASPxComboBox`.
I do know that I can get a value with this way.

```
function(s, e) { grid.PerformCallbacks.GetValue());}
```

But I want to get a value at grid_selecting event with this way.

```
string strCombo = cbComboBox.value.ToString();
DateTime dtDate = dtDateedit.value.ToString();
```

When I tried this way, the return value does not changed.

Comment: Can you post relevant part of your grid markup? Also, what should `grid.PerformCallbacks.GetValue()` do? Shouldn't you call `grid.PerformCallback()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected item:

```
// The key
cbComboBox.SelectedItem.Value  
// The display value
cmbtest.SelectedItem.Text
```

To get the date:

```
dtDateedit.Date;
```

Comment: It may work for the first time. But it does not get new value when the index is changed.

Comment: Are you modifing either of these values during the callback? If so, these changes won't persist, see [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18387.aspx) for more info on callback. Also that link has an example for updating an external control during a callback.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this SelectedindexChanged Event [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

```
protected void cbComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSelectedVar = cbComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the dateedit control in devex grid and get the value:

```
string dtDate = ((ASPxDateEdit)wgvTripSchedule.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl((GridViewDataColumn)wgvTripSchedule.Columns["dtDateeditCol"], "dtDateedit")).Text;
```